# Titanium Saving the Recorded Audio Files in a folder, Uploading audio files to Web Server,

Tags: iphone, file-upload, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

How to save the file which is recorded in sound_record.js File from Appcellrator Titanium KitchenSick Demo.

file = recording.stop(); // file container TiFile Object

sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({sound:file}); // Sound Contains. TiMedia Object

I found these two lines which has the data, which is recorded, But i didnt get that, How to save these recorded data into iphone, so that they can have an access to these files which is recorded.

And also Uploading the Audio files to Web Server, Every where we have how to upload the Image which comes from Gallery, But there is no where its mentioned how we can upload the audio files such as .wav file which is recorded using sound_record.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would checkout the [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples), you'll find a lot of examples there. For saving I would checkout the [filesystem.js](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/filesystem.js) and for upload the [xhr_fileupload.js](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/xhr_fileupload.js).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brain, But, How do i convert the TiObject file to TiFileSystemFile Object, Because in order to create the file from object it must be TiFileSystemFile type.